# Problem when trying to update the result of a specific select

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-update, inner-join

I have the following query  to aleatory select up discounted product registrations. This works perfectly.

```
SELECT * FROM products AS r1 
JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM products)) AS id) AS r2 
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
AND discount_rate <> 0 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 15
```

Okay, but how do I fill these records with information. I am trying to indicate that they are able to appear in a special offers section. From the query that works, I wrote the following update query that doesn't work:

```
UPDATE products 
SET is_special_offer=1 
WHERE IN (SELECT * FROM products AS r1 
  JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM products)) AS id) AS r2 
  WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
  AND discount_rate <> 0 
  ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 15)
```

> Error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

I don't know how to update these results. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL, you could turn the `select` to an `update` like so:

```
update products p
inner join (select ceil(rand() * max(id)) as id from products) p1 on p1.id >= p.id 
set p.is_special_offer = 1
where p.discount_rate <> 0 
order by p.id 
limit 15
```

MySQL does support `orderby`/`limit` in update queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The command was accepted, however, I have several products with discounted rate <> 0 and it does not update any of these products once. Always displaying as answer to command  "0 line affected"

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed it works, it updates after I ran it several times. The point is that RAND () is probably considering "0". For me to indicate that the value must start with 1 up to the maximum ID, what should I do in the RAND?

Comment: @gelsonalves: that would be: `floor(1 + rand() * (max(id) - 1))`. See the example given in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand/